# How do I refer the next item after the top K item?

Tags: expressions

I have the following sentence

```
The top 10 most frequent item are {1, 2, ..., }
```

After the above sentence, what's the appropriate way to refer to the next item?

```
(1) The next 10 item are {,...,}
(2) The next top 10 item are {,...,}
```

Do both work in academic writing?

Comment: 1. The 10 most frequent items are.. 2. The next 10 are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence should be "The ten most frequently (bought, listed, viewed) items are..."
The second sentence should be "the next ten most frequently (bought, listed, viewed) items are..."